# Server for android application

Tags: android, сервер, база-данных

Здравствуйте.

Недавно начал работать с андроид, уже немного понимаю, как работать с GUI (был довольно немалый опыт работы с Windows forms), раньше писал локальные приложения, которые максимум парсили страницы в интернете (работал на Dod.net C#, с обменом информацией поработал с сокетами и WCF, но опять же, всё локально (чаты на компе и прочее)).

Не понимаю, как осуществить такую задачу: есть сервер в инете, на него надо положить БД (тоже есть опыт, но опять же локально), как это сделать? Как будет происходить обращение к серверу с мобилы, например, чтобы при нажатии кнопки скачивался файл картинки, соотвестветствующий данному пользователю или его выбору.

Напишите, пожалуйста, общую последовательность действий, по возможности максимально подробно, хотя любому совету буду рад.

Comment: @ssstik1, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Здесь нужно определится с сервером. Проще всего сделать сайт с БД на PHP.
Клиентом будет выступать android приложение, которое может общаться с сервером обычными post и get запросами.
[Здесь](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNetworking/article.html) описывается способ получения файла/страницы/таблицы в android приложении.